# Date validation(MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, datetime

Here is my code for controller to make an appointment.I would like to show error message to user if he/she choose date before today.How can I do it?

```
public ActionResult Make(Models.AppModel User)
        {
            if (Session["UserEmail"] != null)
            {
                using (var db = new MaindbModelDataContext())
                {
                    var patient = db.Patients.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == (String)Session["UserEmail"]);
                    var app = new Appointment();
                    if(app.Date>System.Date){
                    app.Date = User.Date;
                    }
                    else{ModelState.AddModelError("Date", "Date is invalid");}
                    app.Description = User.Description;
                    app.Status = "isPending";
                    app.PatientNo = patient.PatientNo;
                    app.AppNo = Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode();
                    db.Appointments.InsertOnSubmit(app);
                    db.SubmitChanges();


                    return RedirectToAction("Make", "Appointment");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to use DateTime to get the current date is `DateTime.Now.Date`. So in your code for example:

```
if (app.Date > DateTime.Now.Date)
```

The way your code is currently using the DateTime type is not valid.

Comment: so i used it.It didnt write the date to database but i didnt get any error like this  else{ModelState.AddModelError("Date", "Date is invalid");}

Comment: If you're not seeing the error message, make sure you have a ValidationMessage element in your view using Html.ValidationMessage("Date")